# How to navigate from splash screen to Onboarding Screens?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, native

**This is SplashScreen.js page**

I want to get the splash screen displayed and goes invisible by a timeout and then navigate to Onboarding Screen (sliding splash screens)

```
import React from 'react';
import { View} from 'react-native';

import LogoImage from './LogoImage.js'
import styles from '../stylesheets/SplashStylesheet.js'


const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
render() {
        let that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){that.setState({timePassed: true})}, 1000);
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        if (!this.state.timePassed){
           return (
          <View
                style = {styles.splashScreen}>
                <LogoImage/>
          </View>
        );
    }
    else{
        () => navigate('Onboarding);
    }

export default SplashScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [timePassed, setTimePassed] = useState(false);

  setTimeout(function () {
    setTimePassed(true);
  }, 5000);

  if (!timePassed) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.splash}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Splash Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  navigation.navigate('Onboarding Screen');
  return null;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  splash: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: "100vh"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20
  }
});

export default SplashScreen;
```

I set an alert when navigation happens for now. You can change it to redirect.

In your `App.js` you need to have a `stackNavigator` setup like below which gives the `navigation` prop.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Splash Screen" >
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash Screen" component={SplashScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Main Page" component={OnboadingPage} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-violet-7lqqr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Hiruni Liyanage, check this out !!

Comment: Thankyou, How to redirect to the onboarding pages?

Comment: @HiruniLiyanage, I have updated the answer !

Comment: Thankz.... can you check on this as well! >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429822/how-to-navigate-from-one-screen-to-another-in-react-native?noredirect=1#comment124499082_70429822

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera if I use `navigation` directly, if returns a render warning - cannot update a component while rendering a different component -, but it navigate to the page wanted anyway since its only an warning. However, if I use an anonymous function like `() => navigation...`, the page remain blank without error. How do I solve this?