# How to navigate from one screen to another in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

When I click on Sign Up button I want to navigate to Sign up page but it did not work. I have imported the screens and navigated screen also to app.js file. I am getting an ReferenceError : Can't find variable: navigation. Also I am unable to insert background image? Below is the Sign Up page.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,ImageBackground,Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from   'react-native';
let bgImage='../../resources/images/bg2.png'
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
      state={
        email:"",
        password:"",
      }
      render(){
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.logo}>Trollo</Text>
           <View style={styles.box}>
            <View style={styles.inputView} >
              <TextInput
                style={styles.inputText}
                placeholder="Email"
                placeholderTextColor="#808080"
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({email:text})}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputView} >
              <TextInput
                secureTextEntry
                style={styles.inputText}
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor="#808080"
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({password:text})}/>
           </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn}>
               <Text style={styles.loginText}>SIGN IN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.forgot}>Forgot Password?</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
            <Text style={styles.text1}>New Here?</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupBtn} onPress = {(navigation) => navigation.navigate('Sign Up')}>
              <Text style={styles.loginText}>SIGN UP</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.logoText}>Trollo</Text>
        </View>
        );
      }
    }


});
```

Comment: meka balanna https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875496/how-to-navigate-from-one-screen-to-another-scree-in-react-native

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate from one screen to another scree in react native>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875496/how-to-navigate-from-one-screen-to-another-scree-in-react-native)

Comment: I tried as that, but still it doesnt work

Comment: where do you call `navigation.navigate` ? can you please add the code related to the error?

Comment: I input the code! check now! @AmilaSenadheera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onPress` handler does not getting called with `navigation` as the first parameter. That is `undefined`. `navigation` is a prop to your class component which is provided by stack navigator setup.

Instead of

```
onPress = {(navigation) => navigation.navigate('Sign Up')}
```

use

```
onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Sign Up')}
```

Comment: @Hiruni Liyanage, check this out !!

Comment: I tried this but an error occurs??? https://ibb.co/mXXJGdj

Comment: I removed render and then this error comes? https://ibb.co/9qzRx4J

Comment: seems you have changed your component to a function component. Need to remove `this.props`. use `onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Sign Up')} `

Comment: It worked thankyou

Comment: Can you please mention how to insert background image and logo image which I have commented in the above cord